# Tomcat uninstall problems

Tags: tomcat, uninstall

I am using "apt-get remove tomcat6" to remove tomcat.It gives this outout and tomcat still running on my system:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  seamonkey-gnome-support ocaml-base-nox libghc6-hsql-prof libgmp3-dev
  libffi-dev libtool libghc6-hsql-dev libgmpxx4ldbl ghc6-prof camlp4 ghc6
  ledit ocaml-interp rhino libltdl-dev ocaml-nox
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  tomcat6 tomcat6-admin tomcat6-examples
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
After this operation, 2,400kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Segmentation fault
deepak@kalpna-desktop:~$ apt-get remove tomcat6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  seamonkey-gnome-support ocaml-base-nox libghc6-hsql-prof libgmp3-dev
  libffi-dev libtool libghc6-hsql-dev libgmpxx4ldbl ghc6-prof camlp4 ghc6
  ledit ocaml-interp rhino libltdl-dev ocaml-nox
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  tomcat6 tomcat6-admin tomcat6-examples
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
After this operation, 2,400kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Segmentation fault
```

What is the way to re-install tomcat on ubuntu.

Regards
D

Answer (score -1):

The way to reinstall is normally

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall tomcat6
```

or

```
sudo aptitude reinstall tomcat6
```

but looking at your output that might not work.  Try stopping tomcat first:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 stop
```

and then run one of the above reinstall commands